# Second shipment tax class

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping-tax

Is it possible to add a second shipment tax in Magento. Currently all the products have a 6% tax rate and the shipment has also a 6% tax rate. Now we need to add products which has 21% tax rate and the shipment tax rate needs to work as following:

- If there are only products with 6% tax rate on checkout, than shipment tax rate is also 6%
- If there are only products with 21% tax rate on checkout, than shipment tax rate is also 21%
- If there are products with 6% and products with 21%, than shipment tax needs to be 21%

Does someone know if this is possible inside magento? I have looked around but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 3):

We have the same "problem" in germany, and [MageSetup](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup) solves this (but solves 100 other problems too), but you can at least check the code if you don't want to install everything.

What it does:

- Take the shipping tax which is configured
- Take the highest tax which is used by the products
- calculate the totals and take the shipping tax with the highest share (prices without tax)